# Visual Studio 2003 static library with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, static-libraries

Is it possible to use a static library(.lib) that was compiled with **Visual Studio 2003** inside a **Visual Studio 2010** solution assuming memory is allocated inside the lib and deallocated outside the lib.

Recompiling the lib is not possible since the source code is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, odds are quite good.  The library still gets linked to the 2010 version of the CRT so there is no issue with different heaps getting used.  You will however run into trouble if you used any of the C++ template classes.  Just because their internal structure may have changed.  Particularly an issue with the iterator debugging feature.